# JSSOR Slider and Drupal 7 error

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

Newbie in Drupal

Ok I wrote up a script to intialize the jssor-slider which I include in my themes .js files.

Here is what I wrote this far.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    alert("nikos");
});
```

I also included the `jssor.slider.js` file in the theme's js files.
Following that I edited the .info file to include the files in Drupal.

```
scripts[] = js/jssor.slider.js
scripts[] = js/jssor.slider-initializer.js
```

For some reason I keep getting this in Chrome:

**`Uncaught ReferenceError: $JssorEventManager$ is not defined`**

Comment: the alert is just there for ''test'' purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the minified jssor.slider.mini.js instead.

jssor.slider.mini.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js)

For development, you can use jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js

For release, you need jssor.slider.mini.js only

Comment: Thanks, I already figured it out. What I couldn't do is to make it use a navigation menu with bulllets as well. I just type down the jQuery examples as you have them there and it does not work, it just stays the same..

Comment: Which example? Any url of your demo that I can access online?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/8VRZv/   There is no CDN for JSSOR therefore I can't exactly make it run. But that's the code I am writing down. The slider displays just fine but without the bullet-style navigator.

Comment: Open 'skin\bullet-01.source.html' and copy content between <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin --> and <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->. And paste it into your 'slider1_container'.

Comment: Can i ask what made you pick that naming convention? it is very difficult to understand which one to use.

Comment: Typically, minified js file comes with extension 'min.js', but jssor slider has 2 versions, the size of  jssor.slider.mini.js is smaller.